# How do I stop my Skype automatically setting up a billing agreement with PayPal every time I buy credit?

Tags: paypal

Surely it is not correct for Skype to be able to collect and use my PayPal password to take money out of my PayPal account without me filling in my password .. by automatically setting up a billing agreement with PayPal every time I buy credit .. even though I always take out the tick from the auto recharge box.

How come before you can click Agree and Pay you HAVE to accept the sentence?:

> I authorise Skype to charge my PayPal account for recurring payments.

I do not want to authorise Skype to be able to use my PayPal account and assurances from the Skype chat people that this sentence means nothing, if the auto recharge box is not ticked are UNTRUE.

In order to stop Skype being able to use my PayPal account without my authorisation, I have to manually cancel the agreement they set up every time I buy credit.

This is NOT GOOD and is an invasion of my privacy and MUST STOP !!